# Spring-mongodb query does not fetch results for LocalDate argument

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mongodb

I have a repository method like this

```
    @Query({'date': ?0})
    public List<Log> findForDate(LocalDate date);
```

and I am using it like this

```
repository.findForDate(LocalDate.now());
```

because I want to fetch my current log entries. Repo returns empty List. I enabled query logging and generated query looks like this

> ReactiveMongoTemplate - find using query: { "date" : { "$eq" : { "$date" : -389232000000 } } }

Obviously this is not a correct query, because instead of a number -389232000000 I would expect formatted date String. What am I doing wrong?